# Delete all rows in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Normaly i would do a `delete * from XXX` but on this table thats very slow, it normaly has about 500k to 1m rows in it ( one is a varbinary(MAX) if that mathers ).

Basicly im wondering if there is a quick way to emty the table of all content, its actualy quicker to drop and recreate it then to delete the content via the delete sql statement

The reason i dont want to recreate the table is because its heavly used and delete/recreate i assume will destroy indexs and stats gathered by sql server

Im also hoping there is a way to do this because there is a "clever" way to get row count via sys.sysindexes , so im hoping there is a equaly clever way to delete content

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`Truncate table` is faster than `delete * from XXX`. `Delete` is slow because it works one row at a time. There are a few situations where truncate doesn't work, which you can read about on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: this also has the effect of not adding the rows deleted to the transaction log.. Thus, it can't be rolled back, but also won't waste a bunch of disk space

Answer (score 25):

As other have said, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is far quicker, but it does have some restrictions (taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)):

> You cannot use TRUNCATE TABLE on tables that:
>   - Are referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (You can truncate a table that has a foreign key that references itself.)
>   - Participate in an indexed view.
>   - Are published by using transactional replication or merge replication.
>   For tables with one or more of these characteristics, use the DELETE statement instead.

The biggest drawback is that if the table you are trying to empty has foreign keys pointing to it, then the truncate call will fail.

Comment: ,Awesome Explanation. +1 for Truncate

Answer (score 12):

You can rename the table in question, create a table with an identical schema, and then drop the original table at your leisure.

See the MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual for the [`RENAME TABLE`][1] and [`CREATE TABLE`][2] commands.

```
RENAME TABLE tbl TO tbl_old;

CREATE TABLE tbl LIKE tbl_old;

DROP TABLE tbl_old; -- at your leisure
```

This approach can help minimize application downtime.

Comment: This is not valid for SQl Server? RENAME is a stored procedure called sp_rename in SQL Server (usage: sp_rename 'oldtable', 'newtablename')… as far as I can also tell CREATE TABLE x LIKE y also is invalid as you cannot compare a table that does not exist to an existing table?

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using TRUNCATE TABLE, it's quicker and uses less resources than DELETE FROM xxx

Here's the related [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621(SQL.80).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

[Truncate table in MS Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

[Truncate table in Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html)

Comment: Mysql link is broken.

Comment: Correct link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html